# incrementing array value by one in python

Tags: python, api, postman

In the code, I need to increment "age" by one, and "age" needs to start at 24. I was thinking of making another function that would feed into def getResults and increment "age" by one from that function. Don't know how to do that. New to this. Please help. Thanks!

```
import pprint


def getResults():
    mylist = []
    for n in range(1, 37 + 1):
        currentRow = {"age": n, "numOfYears": n,
                      "beginningBalance": n, "currentSalary": 72_000.00,
                      "dividendsAndGrowth": n, "yearlyDeposit": 8_640.00,
                      "yearlyTotal": n}
        mylist.append(currentRow)

    return mylist


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = getResults()
    pprint.pprint(z)
```

Comment: your description metioned `24`, code has `37` both are magic numbers, please explain.

Comment: So yes there are 37 lines in this database file, but the first line starts at the age of 24. (Also the numOfYears represents number of years which is 37. Just adding this detail just in case. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
import pprint


def getResults():
    mylist = []
    for n in range(1, 37 + 1):
        currentRow = {"age": 23+n, "numOfYears": n,
                      "beginningBalance": n, "currentSalary": 72_000.00,
                      "dividendsAndGrowth": n, "yearlyDeposit": 8_640.00,
                      "yearlyTotal": n}
        mylist.append(currentRow)

    return mylist


if __name__ == "__main__":
    z = getResults()
    pprint.pprint(z)
```

Comment: `23 + n % (n + 1)` is exactly equivalent to `23 + n` for non-negative `n` (which is always the case here). Why did you put the `% (n + 1)` in here?

Comment: yes, thank you! I knew it had to be something that simple. I have to brush up on my python. Didn't even know you can do that. I'm more of a Java guy. Any referrals to learning simple python syntax and calculations are highly appreciated.

Comment: @Junior: There's [a tutorial on the official Python website](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: @ShadowRanger that's a good point lol